"Device not configured" after external HD improperly unmounted
I accidently unplugged my external HD before the eject was done :-/
/Volumes/Red is still there and can't be deleted.
The HD still mounts but as /Volumes/Red 1.
How can I remove /Volumes/Red?
$ gls -lhA /Volumes/

gls: cannot access '/Volumes/Red': Device not configured
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?                ?  Red


Info: macOS Ventura 13.6.7

Is this after a restart of the OS?

Restart with the drive not connected, then go to /Volumes and clean up the old mount point(s).

I believe you are not supposed to ask the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites. This question was asked at superuser approximately one hour before posting here.

@DavidAnderson I don't know ‍♂️

David is correct, it’s almost impossible to ask the exact same question on several sites and have it be on topic in each. This is due to the research requirements where we expect people to do and then document their research before asking a question. Each site has different expectations on how “research” is done in addition to wording and tags that are site specific.

I should have tried turning it off and on again 
